# Azure DevOps Dashboard - List of "Shared Queries" is empty when trying to configure widgets

Tags: azure

In Azure DevOps I am trying to create a new dashboard and populate it with widgets.  When I create a new widget and try to assign a query to it no queries are showing up.
[screenshot showing empty list of queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMoTo.png)

I have created several queries in the "Shared Queries" group, but they just are not showing up.  I then created a sub-folder in the "Shared Queries" group but this makes no difference. 
[screenshot of 4 queries saved in "Shared Queries" group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SJ6s.png)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a browser session issue, I had the same problem for an hour.  I opened Edge instead of Chrome and it showed up, then I reopened Chrome and they were there too.  Guessing you probably resolved your own issue just by trying again later.